# Pull out random element from a list to reach the desired sum

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a number, suppose it is "170".
Near that, I have a list of numbers between 4 and 15.

I have to pull off 25 items of my list, for a total of 170. Items are pulled of randomly. How can I make my algo to compute that for reach this amount of 170 ?

For imaging that, let's consider an exemple :
maxValue = 170
myList = [] # a list of thousands items coming from a database, which all have a value between 4 and 15.
and now, exctract 25 items randomly from myList and reach the amount of 170. The amount can eventually be 1 o r 2 units less, but never more...

Please let me know if you have an example of an algorithm doing that purpose.

For information, I'm developping this in Python.

Comment: 0-1 knapsack seems like the right approach

Comment: You want to know how to calculate the sum? Are they pulled randomly with replacement or removed from the list? Do you know the counts of each number in your random list? Do you want to know how to select a random item? You should clarify the problem, and post some algorithm you tried, to allow us to see where your problem lies.

Comment: Thank's. Items are pulled randomly, and I have to count the sum of weigths to reach the total (here, 170) as close as possible. A bit like the way we would fill a shopping cart, with the goal of spent exactly the money we have :) It's a bit hard to explain, but I hope I'm more clear

Comment: Try to clarify your question.  When you get a point where all aspects of the problem are clearly stated, you will probably already know the answer. (or at least people will be able to help)

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.

If you draw 25 elements randomly, you have no control over the sum they make. In general it will be far from the requested 170. (If your numbers are uniformly distributed in [4,15], the expected sum is 237.5, with standard deviation 3.452...
You are more than 19 σ away !)